# Is it possible to open two instances of power point on windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-office

Is it possible to open two instances of power point on windows XP? I would like to edit one document on one screen and another document on another screen.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PowerPoint 2010, it will do it natively. If not:

Use another account or create a new one in XP. From a higher level account, run PowerPoint using the other account:

```
runas /user:myaccount “c:\program files\microsoft office\office11\POWERPNT.EXE”
```

(Replace the path with your machine's path to `POWERPNT.EXE`)

Answer (score 0):

New documents can be seperated from existing ones in PowerPoint 2010 anyway, simply by dragging the new document to the other screen.

If this doesn't work then you may be able to use the same trick as we use for Excel; once you've opened PowerPoint launch it again, in Excel this opens a second version of the program.